# Python Saving Plots Using For Loops

Tags: python, for-loop, save, directory

I am trying to save multiple plots in Python to a specific folder in Python, but keep getting errors when trying to save. The relevant parts of the code are:

```
etf_name={"AGG", "EFA", "GLD", "IVV", "QQQ", "SPY", "VEA", "VOO", "VTI", "VWO"}
for q in etf_name:
    (Plot created here)
    plt.savefig("/Users/User_Name/Documents/College/'Graphs'/q+"_Golden_Cross".png")
```

For example for AGG, I am trying to have the file be saved as AGG_Golden_Cross.png

Thank you!

Comment: plt.savefig("/Users/User_Name/Documents/College/Graphs/"+q+"_Golden_Cross.png")

Its like path+name+extn

Comment: and what are the errors that you get?

Comment: I keep getting the error: 
    `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "/Users/User_name/Documents/College/'Senior Year'/'Big Data in Python/'Moving Average Strategies on ETFs'/'Graphs'/AGG_Golden_Cross.png"`

Answer (score 0):

Your quotes are placed a bit weirdly.

```
 plt.savefig("/Users/User_Name/Documents/College/'Graphs'/" + q + "_Golden_Cross.png")
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, there is a mistake somewhere in the path. Try saving in the current directory and/or verify the path.

```
etf_name={"AGG", "EFA", "GLD", "IVV", "QQQ", "SPY", "VEA", "VOO", "VTI", "VWO"}
for q in etf_name:
    # (Plot created here)
    plt.savefig(q + "_Golden_Cross.png")
```